# Preventing a CheckBox on the top of a GroupBox to be a child control?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, groupbox

I want to set a CheckBox on the top of a GroupBox like in this picture to enable/ disable the groupBox:

[image]

but in this position, the checkBox is contained within the GroupBox child controls, so it is disabled once I disable the GroupBox..

So Is there a way to keep it in this location , but excluding it from the groupBox controls?
I tried, Bring to front, but doesn't help!

Comment: Have a [look at this](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/make-a-checked-groupbox-in-c/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to do this via the designer? If so, then as soon as you move the `CheckBox` over the `GroupBox`, the designer will automatically assume (not unreasonably), that you want the `CheckBox` to be contained by the `GroupBox`.

To get around this, drag the `CheckBox` *outside* of the `GroupBox`, right-click on the `CheckBox` and select "Bring to Front" so that it will be drawn on top, and then edit the `CheckBox`'s position manually via the `Location` property in the Properties window.

Don't modify the `CheckBox`'s position via the mouse afterwards or the designer will put it back into the `GroupBox` and you'll have to reposition manually again.

Alternatively you can do this programmatically as seen [here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/make-a-checked-groupbox-in-c/) (credit [o_O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6611487/o-o)).